# What is the best way to test for an empty string in Go?

Tags: string, go, is-empty

Which method is best (most idomatic) for testing non-empty strings (in Go)?

```
if len(mystring) > 0 { }
```

Or:

```
if mystring != "" { }
```

Or something else?

Answer (score 705, accepted):

Both styles are used within the Go's standard libraries.

```
if len(s) > 0 { ... }
```

can be found in the `strconv` package: http://golang.org/src/pkg/strconv/atoi.go

```
if s != "" { ... }
```

can be found in the `encoding/json` package: http://golang.org/src/pkg/encoding/json/encode.go

Both are idiomatic and are clear enough. It is more a matter of personal taste and about clarity.

Russ Cox writes in a [golang-nuts thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/7Ks1iq2s7FA):

> The one that makes the code clear.
>   If I'm about to look at element x I typically write
>   len(s) > x, even for x == 0, but if I care about
>   "is it this specific string" I tend to write s == "".
>
> It's reasonable to assume that a mature compiler will compile
>   len(s) == 0 and s == "" into the same, efficient code.
>   ...
>
> Make the code clear.

As pointed out in [Timmmm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54804858/694331), the Go compiler does generate identical code in both cases.

Comment: I don't agree with this answer. Simply `if mystring != "" { }` is the best, preferred and idiomatic way TODAY. The reason standard library contains otherwise is because it was written before 2010 when the `len(mystring) == 0` optimization made sense.

Comment: @honzajde Just tried to validate your statement, but found commits in the standard library less than 1 year old using `len` to check empty/non-empty strings. Like this [commit](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/802cb5927f1e163749331c9f6cfb414cb0c753b9) by Brad Fitzpatrick. I am afraid it is still a matter of taste and clarity ;)

Comment: @honzajde Not trolling. There are 3 len keywords in the commit. I was referring to `len(v) > 0` in *h2_bundle.go* (line 2702). It is not automatically shown as it is generated from golang.org/x/net/http2, I believe.

Comment: If it's noi in the diff then it's not new. Why don't you post direct link? Anyways. enough detective work for me... I don't see it.

Comment: @honzajde You actually have to expand the diff on that file because it's so large.

Comment: nice answer

`find  /usr/local/go/src  -type f -name "*.go" -exec grep '!= ""' {} \; | wc`


1400 plus examples in the go src

Answer (score 46):

This seems to be premature microoptimization. The compiler is free to produce the same code for both cases or at least for these two

```
if len(s) != 0 { ... }
```

and

```
if s != "" { ... }
```

because the semantics is clearly equal.

Comment: agreed, however, it really depends on the implementation of string... If strings are implemented like pascal then len(s) is executed in o(1) and if like C then it's o(n). or whatever, since len() has to execute to completion.

Comment: Have you looked at the code generation to see if the compiler anticipates this or are you only suggesting that a compiler could implement this?

Answer (score 44):

Assuming that empty spaces and all leading and trailing white spaces should be removed:

```
import "strings"
if len(strings.TrimSpace(s)) == 0 { ... }
```

Because :
`len("")  // is 0`
`len(" ")  // one empty space is 1`
`len("  ")  // two empty spaces is 2`

Comment: Why do you have this assumption? The guy clearly tells about the empty string. The same way you can tell, assuming that you want only ascii characters in a string and then add a function that removes all non-ascii chars.

Comment: Because len("") , len(" ") and len("     ")  are not the same thing in go. I was assuming he wanted to make sure that a variable he had initialized to one of those earlier is indeed still "technically" empty.

Comment: This is actually exactly what I needed from this post. I need the user input to have at least 1 non-whitespace character and this one-liner is clear and concise. All I need to do is make the if condition `< 1` +1

Answer (score 28):

Checking for length is a good answer, but you could also account for an "empty" string that is also only whitespace. Not "technically" empty, but if you care to check:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "strings"
)

func main() {
  stringOne := "merpflakes"
  stringTwo := "   "
  stringThree := ""

  if len(strings.TrimSpace(stringOne)) == 0 {
    fmt.Println("String is empty!")
  }

  if len(strings.TrimSpace(stringTwo)) == 0 {
    fmt.Println("String two is empty!")
  }

  if len(stringTwo) == 0 {
    fmt.Println("String two is still empty!")
  }

  if len(strings.TrimSpace(stringThree)) == 0 {
    fmt.Println("String three is empty!")
  }
}
```

Comment: `TrimSpace` will allocate and copy a new string from the original string, so this approach will introduce inefficiencies at scale.

Comment: @Dai looking at the source code, that would be only true if, given `s` is of type string, `s[0:i]` returns a new copy. Strings are immutable in Go, so does it need to create a copy here?

Comment: @MichaelPaesold Right - `strings.TrimSpace( s )` will not cause new string allocation and character copy if the string doesn't need trimming, but if the string does need trimming then the extra copy (without whitespace characters) will be invoked.

Comment: "technically empty" is the question.

Comment: The `gocritic` linter suggests using `strings.TrimSpace(str) == ""` instead of the length check.

Answer (score 22):

As per official guidelines and from performance point of view they appear equivalent ([ANisus answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18595217/5488337)), the s != "" would be better due to a syntactical advantage. s != "" will fail at compile time if the variable is not a string, while len(s) == 0 will pass for several other data types.

Comment: There was a time when I counted CPU cycles and reviewed the assembler that the C compiler produced and deeply understood the structure of C and Pascal strings... even with all the optimizations in the world `len()` requires just that little extra bit of work. HOWEVER, one thing we used to do in C was cast the left side to a `const` or put the static string on the left side of the operator to prevent s=="" from becoming s="" which in the C syntax is acceptable... and probably golang too. (see the extended if)

Answer (score 18):

As of now, the Go compiler generates identical code in both cases, so it is a matter of taste. GCCGo does generate different code, but barely anyone uses it so I wouldn't worry about that.

https://godbolt.org/z/fib1x1

Answer (score 6):

I think `== ""` is faster and more readable.

```
package main 

import(
    "fmt"
)
func main() {
    n := 1
    s:=""
    if len(s)==0{
        n=2
    }
    fmt.Println("%d", n)
}
```

when `dlv debug playground.go` cmp with len(s) and =="" I got this
s == "" situation

```
    playground.go:6         0x1008d9d20     810b40f9        MOVD 16(R28), R1       
    playground.go:6         0x1008d9d24     e28300d1        SUB $32, RSP, R2       
    playground.go:6         0x1008d9d28     5f0001eb        CMP R1, R2             
    playground.go:6         0x1008d9d2c     09070054        BLS 56(PC)             
    playground.go:6         0x1008d9d30*    fe0f16f8        MOVD.W R30, -160(RSP)  

    playground.go:6         0x1008d9d34     fd831ff8        MOVD R29, -8(RSP)      
    playground.go:6         0x1008d9d38     fd2300d1        SUB $8, RSP, R29       
    playground.go:7         0x1008d9d3c     e00340b2        ORR $1, ZR, R0
```

---

```
    playground.go:7         0x1008d9d40     e01f00f9        MOVD R0, 56(RSP)       
    playground.go:8         0x1008d9d44     ff7f05a9        STP (ZR, ZR), 80(RSP)
```

---

```
    playground.go:9         0x1008d9d48     01000014        JMP 1(PC)                        
    playground.go:10        0x1008d9d4c     e0037fb2        ORR $2, ZR, R0
```

len(s)==0 situation

```
    playground.go:6         0x100761d20     810b40f9        MOVD 16(R28), R1       
    playground.go:6         0x100761d24     e2c300d1        SUB $48, RSP, R2       
    playground.go:6         0x100761d28     5f0001eb        CMP R1, R2             
    playground.go:6         0x100761d2c     29070054        BLS 57(PC)             
    playground.go:6         0x100761d30*    fe0f15f8        MOVD.W R30, -176(RSP)  

    playground.go:6         0x100761d34     fd831ff8        MOVD R29, -8(RSP)      
    playground.go:6         0x100761d38     fd2300d1        SUB $8, RSP, R29       
    playground.go:7         0x100761d3c     e00340b2        ORR $1, ZR, R0
```

---

```
    playground.go:7         0x100761d40     e02300f9        MOVD R0, 64(RSP)       
    playground.go:8         0x100761d44     ff7f06a9        STP (ZR, ZR), 96(RSP)  
    playground.go:9         0x100761d48     ff2700f9        MOVD ZR, 72(RSP)
```

---

```
    playground.go:9         0x100761d4c     01000014        JMP 1(PC)              
    playground.go:10        0x100761d50     e0037fb2        ORR $2, ZR, R0         
    playground.go:10        0x100761d54     e02300f9        MOVD R0, 64(RSP)       
    playground.go:10        0x100761d58     01000014        JMP 1(PC)      
    playground.go:6         0x104855d2c     09070054        BLS 56(PC)
```

> Blockquote

Comment: interesting... however, readability depends on whether you THINK in code: "empty string" vs "string of zero length". (I'm not sure how I view it so I will have to catch myself next time). That said, golang treats a string as a slice of runes and I'm not sure if one refers to a slice as empty or zero length. I would imagine that consistency is better. I was once an ASM clock cycle counter but with compiler and runtime optimization I'm not sure counting cycles, jumps, cache invalidation are meaningful anymore. THANKS this brings back memories.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add more to [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18594330/what-is-the-best-way-to-test-for-an-empty-string-in-go/55629309#comment99321111_55629309)

Mainly about how to do performance testing.

I did testing with following code:

```
import (
    "testing"
)

var ss = []string{"Hello", "", "bar", " ", "baz", "ewrqlosakdjhf12934c r39yfashk fjkashkfashds fsdakjh-", "", "123"}

func BenchmarkStringCheckEq(b *testing.B) {
    c := 0
    b.ResetTimer()
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
            for _, s := range ss {
                    if s == "" {
                            c++
                    }
            }
    } 
    t := 2 * b.N
    if c != t {
            b.Fatalf("did not catch empty strings: %d != %d", c, t)
    }
}
func BenchmarkStringCheckLen(b *testing.B) {
    c := 0
    b.ResetTimer()
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
            for _, s := range ss { 
                    if len(s) == 0 {
                            c++
                    }
            }
    } 
    t := 2 * b.N
    if c != t {
            b.Fatalf("did not catch empty strings: %d != %d", c, t)
    }
}
func BenchmarkStringCheckLenGt(b *testing.B) {
    c := 0
    b.ResetTimer()
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
            for _, s := range ss {
                    if len(s) > 0 {
                            c++
                    }
            }
    } 
    t := 6 * b.N
    if c != t {
            b.Fatalf("did not catch empty strings: %d != %d", c, t)
    }
}
func BenchmarkStringCheckNe(b *testing.B) {
    c := 0
    b.ResetTimer()
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
            for _, s := range ss {
                    if s != "" {
                            c++
                    }
            }
    } 
    t := 6 * b.N
    if c != t {
            b.Fatalf("did not catch empty strings: %d != %d", c, t)
    }
}
```

And results were:

```
% for a in $(seq 50);do go test -run=^$ -bench=. --benchtime=1s ./...|grep Bench;done | tee -a log
% sort -k 3n log | head -10

BenchmarkStringCheckEq-4        150149937            8.06 ns/op
BenchmarkStringCheckLenGt-4     147926752            8.06 ns/op
BenchmarkStringCheckLenGt-4     148045771            8.06 ns/op
BenchmarkStringCheckNe-4        145506912            8.06 ns/op
BenchmarkStringCheckLen-4       145942450            8.07 ns/op
BenchmarkStringCheckEq-4        146990384            8.08 ns/op
BenchmarkStringCheckLenGt-4     149351529            8.08 ns/op
BenchmarkStringCheckNe-4        148212032            8.08 ns/op
BenchmarkStringCheckEq-4        145122193            8.09 ns/op
BenchmarkStringCheckEq-4        146277885            8.09 ns/op
```

Effectively variants usually do not reach fastest time and there is only minimal difference (about 0.01ns/op) between variant top speed.

And if I look full log, difference between tries is greater than difference between benchmark functions.

Also there does not seem to be any measurable difference between
BenchmarkStringCheckEq and BenchmarkStringCheckNe
or BenchmarkStringCheckLen and BenchmarkStringCheckLenGt
even if latter variants should inc c 6 times instead of 2 times.

You can try to get some confidence about equal performance by adding tests with modified test or inner loop. This is faster:

```
func BenchmarkStringCheckNone4(b *testing.B) {
    c := 0
    b.ResetTimer()
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
            for _, _ = range ss {
                    c++
            }
    }
    t := len(ss) * b.N
    if c != t {
            b.Fatalf("did not catch empty strings: %d != %d", c, t)
    }
}
```

This is not faster:

```
func BenchmarkStringCheckEq3(b *testing.B) {
    ss2 := make([]string, len(ss))
    prefix := "a"
    for i, _ := range ss {
            ss2[i] = prefix + ss[i]
    }
    c := 0
    b.ResetTimer()
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
            for _, s := range ss2 {
                    if s == prefix {
                            c++
                    }
            }
    }
    t := 2 * b.N
    if c != t {
            b.Fatalf("did not catch empty strings: %d != %d", c, t)
    }
}
```

Both variants are usually faster or slower than difference between main tests.

It would also good to generate test strings (ss) using string generator with relevant distribution. And have variable lengths too.

So I don't have any confidence of performance difference between main methods to test empty string in go.

And I can state with some confidence, it is faster not to test empty string at all than test empty string. And also it is faster to test empty string than to test 1 char string (prefix variant).

Answer (score 0):

It would be cleaner and less error-prone to use a function like the one below:

```
func empty(s string) bool {
    return len(strings.TrimSpace(s)) == 0
}
```

Comment: Using a function name like this implies emtying the string, not checking if its empty

Answer (score -1):

This would be more performant than trimming the whole string, since you only need to check for at least a single non-space character existing

```
// Strempty checks whether string contains only whitespace or not
func Strempty(s string) bool {
    if len(s) == 0 {
        return true
    }

    r := []rune(s)
    l := len(r)

    for l > 0 {
        l--
        if !unicode.IsSpace(r[l]) {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: @Richard that may be, but when Googling for "golang check if string is blank" or things similar, this is the only question that comes up, so for those people this is for them, which isn't an unprecedented thing to do on Stack Exchange

Comment: _"This would be more performant than trimming the whole string"_ — so, show us some proof to that claim, do the benchmarking and show us the results :)

Answer (score -1):

```
   // It will return true, if string is empty of null

    func isEmpty(value string) bool {
        return value == "" || len(value) == 0
    }
```