# How do I check if the user has entered a null value in Go?

Tags: string, go, file-io, null

```
reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
fmt.Print("Enter text: ")
text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
fmt.Println("Hello",text)
```

How do I check if the user has entered a null value and where do I put the code? Note - I've already tried checking the length `= 0` and `= " "` but, they don't seem to be working.

Please suggest an alternative way for doing this. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think "enter a null value" makes sense. Null is the absence of input.  The closest you can get in a stream input would be a 0-length string, but as you know `""` is not the same as `nil` in Go (or almost any language).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18594330/what-is-the-best-way-to-test-for-an-empty-string-in-go

Answer (score 6):

[`bufio.Reader.ReadString()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadString) returns a `string` that also **contains the delimeter**, in this case the newline character `\n`.

If the user does not enter anything just presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, the return value of `ReadString()` will be `"\n"`, so you have to compare the result to `"\n"` to check for empty input:

```
reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
fmt.Print("Enter text: ")
text, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
if err != nil {
    panic(err) // Don't forget to check and handle returned errors!
}

if text == "\n" {
    fmt.Println("No input!")
} else {
    fmt.Println("Hello", text)
}
```

An even better alternative would be to use [`strings.TrimSpace()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#TrimSpace) which removes leading and trailing white space characters (newline included; it isn't a meaningful name if someone inputs 2 spaces and presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>, this solution also filters that out). You can compare to the empty string `""` if you called `strings.TrimSpace()` prior:

```
text = strings.TrimSpace(text)
if text == "" {
    fmt.Println("No input!")
} else {
    fmt.Println("Hello", text)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// The best algorithm I have written so far

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    Wellcome()
    sina := get_Informations()
    fmt.Printf("%v", sina)
    Goodbye()
}

func Wellcome() {
    fmt.Println("Welcome to this Program ...[*]")
}

func get_Informations() (string){
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Enter First-Name: ")
    firstName, _ := reader.ReadString('\n') 
    if len(firstName) >= 5 {
        return firstName
    }
    for {
        fmt.Print("First-Name must be more than 3 characters: ")    
        firstName, _ := reader.ReadString('\n') 
        if len(firstName) < 5 {
            continue
        }else if len(firstName) >=5{
            return firstName
        } 

    }
}

func Goodbye() {
    fmt.Println("   ")
    fmt.Println("   ")
    fmt.Println(" [*]----------------------[*]  ")
    fmt.Println(" [*]----THANKS.GOODBYE----[*]  ")
    fmt.Println(" [*]----------------------[*]  ")
    fmt.Println("   ")
    fmt.Println("   ")
}
```